# Allow {{myVar}} templating in CSS using Monaco Editor

Tags: monaco-editor

How can I allow the following code to be valid in the Monaco Editor?

```
body {
    font-size: {{myVar}}px;  
}
```

I couldn't figure it out using the documentation of Monaco.

Comment: Maybe try a css preprocessor like Scss? Scss is great and supports everything from variables to loops and reusable code blocks.

Comment: What do you mean? It's not valid css and editor will show syntax errors/helpers.

Your code snippet is so out of context to guess anything. But I think you want the `{{myvar}}` to be replaced with a value. If so, why not run it through a template preprocessor.

Comment: But if you mean how to make your custom syntax valid, then you will have to create a module for your custom lang & write custom parse logic etc.
https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-css/blob/master/src/cssWorker.ts#L48 
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-css-languageservice/blob/master/src/parser/cssParser.ts